# Why does dividing with long doubles in c make numbers less precise?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm attempting to isolate the digits of a credit card number (cs50 assignment) by dividing the number one by one with increasing powers of ten.

```
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 100),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 1000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 10000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 100000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 1000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 10000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 100000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 1000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 10000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 100000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 1000000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 10000000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 100000000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 1000000000000000),
                      roundDownSubtract(ccNumber / 10000000000000000),
                      };
```

then I copy the divided number into a separate variable and round the number down. Now I have the credit card number divided by some power of ten, one of which has the decimals and one of the which does not. Thus by subtracting the rounded number from the unrounded number you will be left with just the decimals. Then multiplying by ten and rounding down once more you now have one of the digits of the cc number (depending on what power of ten you divided by initially).

```
long double roundDownSubtract(long double number)
{

    printf("\n%LF\n", number);

    temp = floor(number);
    printf("\n%LF\n", temp);

    temp2 = number - temp;
    printf("\n%LF\n", temp2);

    temp2 = temp2 * 10;
    printf("\n%LF\n", temp2);

    temp2 = floor(temp2);
    printf("\n%LF\n", temp2);

    return temp2;
}
```

the only issue is that when the cc number gets initially divided by some power of ten, it turns numbers like 4 into .3999999, which completely throws off the precise mechanism I created to extract digits one by one.

Example:

```
Number: 4003600000000014

400360000000001.399994
```

This is what happens when the `long double` is divided by 10. I tested to see if the problem was the conversion from `long` to `long double`, but it was not

Comment: Have you thought of converting it to a string and grabbing it's digits using an index value?

Comment: 10 is not a power of 2, so rounding is more likely in the base representation.

Comment: What is `ccNumber`? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Obligatory: credit card numbers are not "numbers" but rather strings of digits. Treat them as such.

Comment: If you insist on doing numeric calculations on the CCN, use a 64-bit (unsigned) integer type.  But it is better to treat the CC "number" as a string of digits.

Answer (score 0):

At least this issue:

**Enable all compiler warnings**

OP's code is calling `double` functions, not `long double` ones and so reduces the precision.  A well enabled compiler will report this.

```
long double roundDownSubtract(long double number) {
    printf("\n%LF\n", number);

    // temp = floor(number);
    temp = floorl(number);

    printf("\n%LF\n", temp);
    ...
```

Note that `long double` is not certain to encode a credit-card number *exactly*.  Avoid floating point for this task.

---

To well handle up to 18 decimal digit credit card numbers, consider `(unsigned) long long` math or perhaps *string* manipulation.

Floating point types are not the right approach here for an *integer* problem.

To get the i'th decimal digit of an `unsigned long long`:

```
// Not highly efficient, but gets the job done.
// i=0 gets the least significant digit.
int ith_digit(unsigned long long number, int i) {
  unsigned long long pow10 = 1;
  while (i > 0) {
    i--;
    pow10 *= 10;
  }
  return (number / pow10) % 10;
}
```

To get the i'th character of a number saved as a *string*:

```
// i=0 gets the least significant digit.
int ith_digit(const char *number, unsigned i) {
  size_t len = strlen(number);
  if (i >= len) {
    return 0;
  }
  assert(isdigit(number[len - i - 1]));
  return number[len - i - 1] - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4/10 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal. As such, `400360000000001.4` can't be accurately represented by a floating point number. Sometimes, it'll be a little higher, sometimes it'll be a little lower.

The nearest `double` in my environment is

```
400360000000001.375
```

The nearest `long double` in my environment is

```
400360000000001.399993896484375
```

---

You could address your issues using `floorl` (which takes a `long double`) instead of `floor` (which takes a `double`).<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>

```c
long double floored = floorl( num / 10 );
int digit = num - ( floored * 10 );
num = floored;
```

You could also address your issue by using integers, which is a bit simpler.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

int digit = ((uint64_t)num) % 10;
num = ( num - digit ) / 10;
```

But there exists an even simpler solution: Don't treat credit card numbers as numbers, but as strings. Extracting a digit becomes a simple case of using array indexing.

---

1. Assuming `long double` in your environment has enough precision.
2. ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings! It would have found this problem. With `gcc` and `clang`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Hard to use array indexing when that hasn't been taught at this point in the course.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, floating point numbers (with fractional parts) *mostly* can only be approximations. (Base10 equivalent example: 1/7. The infinite number of precision digits required means we work with the not-quite-right approximation 0.142857)

The solution to this assignment needs a datatype that can store very large decimal values. C's answer to this (on modern hardware and compilers) is `long long` (or better (`unsigned long long`) providing 64 bits as a single variable.

Here are some fragments of code to help you move forward.

```
    unsigned long long ccNo = get_long( "Enter the card number" );

    unsigned long long x; // used as throw-away copy

    for( x = ccNo; x; x /= 10 ) // shaving off decades per iteration
        printf( "Units digit now: %llu", x%10 ); // digits, in reverse order
```

Counting the number of digits in the cc number:

```
    int nDigit = 0;
    for( x = ccNo; x; x /= 10 )
        nDigit++;
```

Getting the checksum digit:

```
    int chkSum = ccNo % 10;
```

Performing Luhn's validation:

```
    int count = 0;
    for( x = ccNo; x; x /= 10, count++ )
        if( ( count & 1 ) == 0 )
            /* accumulate value of every EVEN # digit */
        else
            /* accumulate value of ODD # digit */
```

Get two digit prefix (when # of digits may be 13, 15 or 16)

```
    for( x = ccNo; x > 99; x /= 10 ) {}
    /* x now holds the value of the highest two digits */
```

If you plan this out, you'll see that all of these functions can be performed *at the same time* (making a single sweep across the ccNo.)

Good luck with your studies..